# R text mining : Grouping of similar patterns from a dataframe.

Tags: r, dataframe, text-mining, tm, names

I have applied various cleaning functions from the `tm` package, like removing punctuation, numbers, special chars, common English words etc. and got a data-frame as shown below. Remember, I don't have a primary-key, like cust_id or account_number to rely on

```
sno        names
001        SIRIS BLACK
002        JOHN DOE
003        STEPHEN HRYY
004        SIRIUS BLACK
005        SIRUS BLACK
006        JON DOE
007        STEPHEN HARRY
008        STIPHEN HURRY
009        JHN DOE
```

Looking at the above data, I can really feel that there is a similarity of patterns and that those names are close to one another. How do I calculate the percentage of equality of patterns using the available text-mining functions of R, so that I can finally get a data-frame with all unique names?

Assumptions and Shortcomings :

1. Just bluntly assuming that unique names, might be the ones with maximum characters, because the raw data that I have has loads of typos on the names. (logical assumption, perhaps will reduce the number of typos)
2. The `agrep()` function searches for approximate matches to pattern within a large string, and problem here is I actually don't know what the patterns are.

Group the similar strings like this :

```
sno        names
001        SIRIS BLACK          
002        SIRIUS BLACK
003        SIRUS BLACK
004        JHN DOE
005        JOHN DOE
006        JON DOE
007        STEPHEN HARRY
008        STIPHEN HURRY
009        STEPHEN HRYY
```

And finally get this :

```
001     JOHN DOE
002     STEPHEN HARRY
003     STIPHEN HURRY
004     SIRIUS BLACK
```

Comment: I'd relegate this kind of tasks to Google Refine.

Comment: I wish I could do that too.. All I am not sure whether it will meet my academic requirements of the R course that I'm pursuing, may cost some of my precious marks... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `agrep` part, here's one way - you can play with the parameters to tune your results:

```
sim <- setNames(lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) agrep(df$names[i], df$names, max.distance = list(all=2, insertions=2, deletions=2, substitutions=0))), df$names)
sim <- lapply(sim, function(x) unique(df$names[x]))
df$names2 <- sapply(sim, "[", 1)
df[!duplicated(df$names2), ]
#   sno         names        names2
# 1   1   SIRIS BLACK   SIRIS BLACK
# 2   2      JOHN DOE      JOHN DOE
# 3   3  STEPHEN HRYY  STEPHEN HRYY
# 8   8 STIPHEN HURRY STIPHEN HURRY
```

Comment: Well well, I got an error.. I shall ping back if I'm not able to resolve it. There is certain "something" I might have missed..

`Error in agrep()  'pattern' must be a non-empty character string` with `try()` , maybe

Comment: perhaps your name column is of type factor, not of type character.

Comment: Actually, there are few empty rows, that's playing a spoilsport, I suppose.

Comment: The example works for your example to showthe  `agrep` idea. You may have to adapt it for the whole data frame.

Comment: Exactly, and it works like a charm. Thanks a ton @lukeA If not getting unique rows, or perfect names, I could able to reduce the number of repetitive rows by almost 53%.. !!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method. It uses the RecordLinkage package and finds the shortest form of a sorted vector.  You can adjust your threshold level.

```
structure(list(sno = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 8L), .Label = c("JHN", "JOHN", "JON", "SIRIS", "SIRIUS", 
"SIRUS", "STEPHEN", "STIPHEN"), class = "factor"), names = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("BLACK", "DOE", "HARRY", 
"HRYY", "HURRY"), class = "factor"), both.names = c("JHN DOE", 
"JOHN DOE", "JON DOE", "SIRIS BLACK", "SIRIUS BLACK", "SIRUS BLACK", 
"STEPHEN HARRY", "STEPHEN HRYY", "STIPHEN HURRY")), .Names = c("sno", 
"names", "both.names"), row.names = c("009", "002", "006", "001", 
"004", "005", "007", "003", "008"), class = "data.frame")

library("RecordLinkage")
compareJW <- function(string, vec, cutoff) {
  require(RecordLinkage)
  jarowinkler(string, vec) > cutoff
}

shortenFirms <- function(firms, cutoff) {
  shortnames <- firms[1]
  firms <- firms[-1]

  for (firm in firms) {
    if (is.na(firm)) { # no firm name, so short-circuit and add an NA
      shortnames <- c(shortnames, NA)
      next

    }
    unique.short <- unique(shortnames[!is.na(shortnames)])
    hits <- compareJW(firm, unique.short, cutoff)
    if (sum(hits) > 1) {
      warning(paste("cassifyFirms: more than one match for", firm))
      shortnames <- c(shortnames, NA)
    } else if (sum(hits) == 0) {
      shortnames <- c(shortnames, firm)
    } else {
      shortnames <- c(shortnames, unique.short[hits])
    }
  }
  shortnames
}

shortenFirms(df$both.names, 0.8)
```

shortenFirms(df$both.names, 0.8)

```
[1] "JHN DOE"       "JHN DOE"       "JHN DOE"       "SIRIS BLACK"   "SIRIS BLACK"   "SIRIS BLACK"   "STEPHEN HARRY"
[8] "STEPHEN HARRY" "STEPHEN HARRY"
```